# Web API Access Route Template inside Custom Action Filter

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to access RouteTemplate inside custom action filter in my Web Api Project.

I have registered a custom action filter to be executed before any action, as below.

```
public class AuthorizationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
      public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
      {

      }
}
```

If you can see in below image I can access route template from Quick Watch inside filter. But if I write same code, it throws an error `'System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute' is inaccessible due to its protection level`

Is there any other way to access route template

Property Using : `(((System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute)(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Route)).HttpRoute).RouteTemplate`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it will work.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
{
       if (Settings.GetKeyValue<string>("EnableAuthorization") == "Enabled")
       {
            var routeTemplate = filterContext.Request.GetRouteData().Route.RouteTemplate;
       }
}
```